# InvalidArgumentException Malformed UTF-8 characters when fetching images

Tags: laravel, lumen

When I try to fetch image its shown error:

> InvalidArgumentException Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly
>   incorrectly encoded

This is my code:

```
public function getImage($id){
    $users = AdminLogin::find($id);
    $path = "uploads/images/{$users->image_file}";

    if(!File::exists($path)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image not found.'], 404);
    }       
    $file = File::get($path);       
    return response()->json($file);     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function getImage($id){
    $users = AdminLogin::find($id);
    $path = "uploads/images/{$users->image_file}";

    if(!File::exists($path)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image not found.'], 404);
    }       
    $file = File::get($path);       
   return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
}
```